# How to fetch data from another table? so that I can make a condition and make a relationship (Laravel + Vue)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

Please help me for developing a website?
 I want to fetch data from the cycles table so that I can make a if condition and make a relationship to moralities table.

The **cycles table** has the following data:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->date('date_start_raise');
$table->integer('population');
$table->integer('raising_days');
$table->date('date_end_raise');
$table->date('date_manure_collection');
$table->date('date_cleaning');
$table->date('date_disinfection');
$table->date('date_rest_day');
$table->date('date_preparation');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->timestamps();
```

The data that I need are **date_start_raise**, **date_end_raise**, and **id**

The **mortalities table** has the following data:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->date('date_input');
$table->integer('number_of_mortality');
$table->integer('chicken_age');
$table->mediumText('cause_of_death')->nullable();
$table->unsignedInteger('cycle_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); 
$table->timestamps();
```

I need to pass **id**(cycle) to **cycle_id**(mortalities).

Before that, I need to make a condition so that the content of mortalities will arrange accordingly by cycle_id and it will make a relationship to the cycles table

The data will be use are **date_input**(mortalities), **date_start_raise**, and **date_end_raise**(cycle).If **data_input** belongs to the **date range from date_start_raise to date_end_raise**, the id will be pass to **cycle_id**.

---

### For Example

There are two data in cycles table
[image]

> (September 3 - 28): id = 1
>  (October 1 - November 5): id= 2

The user opens the mortality modal to input data and send data to mortalities table.

[image]

According to mortality modal, the date(**date_input**) is September 6. The **id** will be be fetch is 1 because the **date_input** belongs of date range(**from date_start_raise to date_end_raise**) September 3 - September 28 and the cycle data’s **id** is 1. After fetching, the value of **id** will pass to **cycle_id**(mortality) so that the two tables have relationship.

---

I try this code but it was an error

> "message": "Call to undefined method App\Cycle::date_start_raise()",

MortalityController.php (store)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $cycle_id = Mortality::whereDate([
     ['date_input','>=', Cycle::date_start_raise()],
     ['date_input','<=', Cycle::date_end_raise()],
   ])->get(Cycle::id());

   $this->validate($request, array(
     'date_input' => 'required|date',
     'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
     'chicken_age' => 'required|numeric'
   ));

   return Mortality::create([
    'date_input' => request('date_input'),
    'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
    'chicken_age' => request('chicken_age'),
    'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
    'cycle_id' => $cycle_id,
    'user_id' => Auth::id()
  ]);
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling data_start_raise() without actually telling it what entry to do it on

```
['date_input','>=', Cycle::date_start_raise()],
 ['date_input','<=', Cycle::date_end_raise()
```

You would have to find an entry for example

```
Cycle::find( id goes here )->date_start_raise()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: `Cycle::find( id goes here )->date_start_raise()` i need the date first. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is impossible. You are calling ->date_start_raise() on a null object. You have to find an object then call something on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function store(Request $request)
        {
         $cycle = Mortality::whereDate([
         [request('date_input'),'>=', Cycle::date_start_raise()],
         [request('date_input'),'<=', Cycle::date_end_raise()],
         ])->get()->first();

         if ($cycle!==NULL)
           { $cycle_id = $cycle->id;}
         else return;//you may send with an error message like invalid date
         //above lines are a little bit changed.

         $this->validate($request, array(
           'date_input' => 'required|date',
           'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
           'chicken_age' => 'required|numeric'
           ));

         return Mortality::create([
           'date_input' => request('date_input'),
           'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
           'chicken_age' => request('chicken_age'),
           'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
           'cycle_id' => $cycle_id,
           'user_id' => Auth::id()
           ]);
       }
```

When you used get method with where clause, you were getting a collection; not a single instance. That is why you couldn't assign the id. By using first(), we are getting a single id.

Comment: why `])->get()->first();` is duplicate?